# Outlook Calendar events not showing to account delegates

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook

We have someone in our organization who has shared his calendar with 2 other users and given them delegate rights. These two users have full edit permissions. Everything was working as intended unto today. One of the delegate users is no longer able to see certain calendar events on the shared calendar. I've removed both delegate users and added them back with full edit delegate permissions. I've then gone to each user's machine and added an event to the shared calendar. They can each see the even that was added from their account, and the owner of the shared calendar can see both, however the 2 delegate users can't see events added from each other. I can't see where there's a syncing issue and both the delegates are working in online mode and the current folders are updating as normal.

Does anyone know what could be causing the calendar events from showing for all three users?

---

My organization contacted Microsoft who admitted that there is an issue going on at the system level and that it's not likely anything we can do to resolve until Microsoft pushes out a fix. Looks like I'm off the hook for this one!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In order to further confirm if the issue is related to Outlook desktop, please log in to the two delegates' account on OWA and open the shared calendar to check if the calendar items as the two delegates created can be displayed successfully.

If it shows normal on the OWA, I'm afraid as you mentioned is the synchronization issue of Outlook client. It's suggested that you could update the folder manually and wait for a moment to check if there're any differences.

[image]

If it doesn't work, considering the impact of some add ins, It is suggested that you try to start outlook in safe mode(win+R>type: outlook /safe) to check whether it works normally.

If this is still the case in safe mode, it is suggested that you could try to create a new profile(Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>add) and add the account for testing to check if there are some differences.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Most of these I tried after posting originally. My organization contacted Microsoft who admitted that there is an issue going on at the system level and that it's not likely anything we can do to resolve until Microsoft pushes out a fix. Looks like I'm off the hook for this one!

Comment: Well, hope your issue will be solved soon!